# Why can't I run my spark python script with Datastax Enterprise?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, datastax, datastax-enterprise

This is my test code and I simply cannot figure out why I cannot run it wit DSE but without it does not seem to be a problem.

This is my python code:

```
from future import print_function
import sys

from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils

if name == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) != 3:
        print("Usage: kafka_wordcount.py <zk> <topic>", file=sys.stderr)
        exit(-1)

    sc = SparkContext(appName="PythonStreamingKafkaWordCount")
    ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 1)

    zkQuorum, topic = sys.argv[1:]
    kvs = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zkQuorum, "spark-streaming-consumer", {topic: 1})
    lines = kvs.map(lambda x: x[1])
    counts = lines.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" ")) \
        .map(lambda word: (word, 1)) \
        .reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a+b)
    counts.pprint()

    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
```

When I runt he code like this it just doesn't work. I don't understand why?
This is my DSE error code:

```
# dse pyspark --jars /root/spark-streaming-kafka-assembly_2.10-1.4.1.jar /root/kafka_wordcount.py localhost:2181 wordcount
WARNING: Running python applications through 'pyspark' is deprecated as of Spark 1.0.
Use ./bin/spark-submit <python file>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/kafka_wordcount.py", line 43, in <module>
    sc = SparkContext(appName="PythonStreamingKafkaWordCount")
  File "/usr/share/dse/resources/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 113, in init
  File "/usr/share/dse/resources/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 165, in _do_init
  File "/usr/share/dse/resources/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 219, in _initialize_context
  File "/usr/share/dse/resources/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 538, in call
  File "/usr/share/dse/resources/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 300, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:com.datastax.bdp.spark.DseSparkContext.apply.
: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
 at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.createTempDir(Utils.scala:225)
 at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$getOrCreateLocalRootDirsImpl$2.apply(Utils.scala:653)
 at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$getOrCreateLocalRootDirsImpl$2.apply(Utils.scala:649)
 at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
 at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
 at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
 at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:108)
 at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:251)
 at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.flatMap(ArrayOps.scala:108)
 at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getOrCreateLocalRootDirsImpl(Utils.scala:649)
 at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getOrCreateLocalRootDirs(Utils.scala:626)
 at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockManager.createLocalDirs(DiskBlockManager.scala:128)
 at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockManager.<init>(DiskBlockManager.scala:45)
 at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.<init>(BlockManager.scala:75)
 at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.<init>(BlockManager.scala:173)
 at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.create(SparkEnv.scala:338)
 at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.createDriverEnv(SparkEnv.scala:188)
 at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.createSparkEnv(SparkContext.scala:267)
 at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:424)
 at com.datastax.bdp.spark.DseSparkContext$.apply(DseSparkContext.scala:42)
 at com.datastax.bdp.spark.DseSparkContext.apply(DseSparkContext.scala)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
 at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
 at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:379)
 at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
 at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
 at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
 at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:207)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: SHUTDOWN_HOOK_PRIORITY
 at java.lang.Class.getField(Class.java:1703)
 at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager.install(ShutdownHookManager.scala:222)
 at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager$.shutdownHooks$lzycompute(ShutdownHookManager.scala:50)
 at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager$.shutdownHooks(ShutdownHookManager.scala:48)
 at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager$.addShutdownHook(ShutdownHookManager.scala:191)
 at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager$.<init>(ShutdownHookManager.scala:58)
 at org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager$.<clinit>(ShutdownHookManager.scala)
 ... 32 more
```

Edit:

After using your advice there seems to be a no class def error now:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kafka/common/TopicAndPartition
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
 at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2902)
 at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1615)
 at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethodsByNameAndLength(ReflectionEngine.java:365)
 at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:317)
 at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:342)
 at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:251)
 at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
 at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
 at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:207)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kafka.common.TopicAndPartition
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
 ... 12 more
```

thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

The error you are seeing is at it's core

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: SHUTDOWN_HOOK_PRIORITY
```

Which lets us know that Spark has found Hadoop2 libraries on your Classpath. Dse 4.8 does not support Hadoop2 and only has hadoop1 libs.

Your use of kafka leads me to suspect that you are including `spark-kafka-assembly` somewhere on your CP.

```
--jars /root/spark-streaming-kafka-assembly_2.10-1.4.1.jar
```

This jar contains Hadoop2 Libs within it and will cause the CP issue. Try using the non assembly jar for `spark-kafka` and everything should work out fine.

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming-kafka_2.10/1.4.1

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried your solution but now there is another problem I added above. Would be great if you could have a look